# Java Prim Algorithm implementation

Tags: java, graph-theory, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to implement prim's algorithm in Java, my algorithm seems to yield correct results in some cases, yet incorrect, or partially correct results in other cases and I can't find out why, this is my code:

Node class

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    private double cost;
    private int dest;
    private int source;
    private Node next;


public Node(double cost, int dest,int source) {
    this.cost = cost;
    this.dest = dest;
    this.source = source;
}
public Node() {

}
public double getCost() {
    return cost;
}
public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}
public int getDest() {
    return dest;
}
public void setDest(int dest) {
    this.dest = dest;
}
public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}
public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}



public int getSource() {
    return source;
}
public void setSource(int source) {
    this.source = source;
}
public int compareTo(Node node) {
    if(this.cost> node.getCost())
        return 1;
    else if (this.cost<node.getCost())
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

}

linked List class:

```
public class LinkedList {
private Node first;
private Node last;
private int counter;

public LinkedList() {

}

public Node getFirst() {
    return first;
}
public Node getLast() {
    return last;
}
public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public Object getFirstNode() {
    if(counter == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return first;

}


public Object getLastNode() {
    if(counter ==0)
        return null;
    else
        return last;
}

public void addLast(double cost,int dest,int source) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        first = last = new Node(cost,dest,source);

    }   
    else {
        Node temp = new Node(cost,dest,source);
        last.setNext(temp);
        last = temp;
    }
    counter++;
}

public void addFirst(double cost,int dest,int source) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        first = last = new Node(cost,dest,source);

    }   
    else {
        Node temp = new Node(cost,dest,source);
        temp.setNext(first);
        first = temp;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

}

Prim algorithm class:

```
public class Prim {
    private double[][] t;
    private LinkedList[] list;
    private PriorityQueue heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>();

public Prim(int vertex) {
    t = new double[vertex][3];
    list = new LinkedList[vertex];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++) {
        list[i] = new LinkedList();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++) {
        t[i][1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}

public void MST(int start) {
    t[start - 1][0] = 1;
    t[start - 1][1] = 0;
    t[start - 1][2] = 0;

    Node node = list[start - 1].getFirst();
    // vertex-1
    while (node != null) {
        t[node.getDest() - 1][1] = node.getCost();
        t[node.getDest() - 1][2] = node.getSource();
        // vertex - 1
        node = node.getNext();
    }

    // debug
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        System.out.println('\n');
        for (int j = 0; j < t[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(t[i][j] + " ");

        }
    }
    System.out.println('\n');

    while (heap.peek() != null) {
        Node minNode = (Node) heap.poll();
        if (t[minNode.getDest() - 1][0] != 1 && minNode.getCost() <= t[minNode.getDest() - 1][1]) {

            t[minNode.getDest() - 1][0] = 1;

            Node adjacent = list[minNode.getDest() - 1].getFirst();

            while (adjacent != null ) {
                if (t[adjacent.getDest() - 1][0] != 1 && (adjacent.getCost()<t[adjacent.getDest() - 1][1])) {

                    t[adjacent.getDest() - 1][1] = adjacent.getCost();
                    t[adjacent.getDest() - 1][2] = adjacent.getSource();
                }

                adjacent = adjacent.getNext();
            }
        }
    }


}

public void addNode(int index, int cost, int dest) {
    list[index - 1].addLast(cost, dest, index);
    heap.add(new Node(cost, dest, index));
}
public PriorityQueue getHeap() {
    return heap;
}

public void setHeap(PriorityQueue heap) {
    this.heap = heap;
}

public double[][] getT() {
    return t;
}

public void setT(double[][] t) {
    this.t = t;
}
```

}

In the driver class:

```
Prim prim = new Prim(4);
    prim.addNode(1, 5, 2);
    prim.addNode(1, 4, 4);

    prim.addNode(2, 5, 1);
    prim.addNode(2, 3, 3);
    prim.addNode(2, 2, 4);

    prim.addNode(3, 3, 2);
    prim.addNode(3, 6, 4);

    prim.addNode(4, 4, 1);
    prim.addNode(4, 6, 3);
    prim.addNode(4, 2, 2);
    prim.MST(4);
```

Generates proper results if you print the table t using prim.getT() and iterate over 2d array:(k: known, d cost, p path or node through which I move). Note that since the graph is directed, it is necessary to say:  prim.addNode(1, 5, 2) where 1 is source, 2 destination and 5 cost, and also: prim.addNode(2, 5, 1) where 2 source, 1 cost and 5 destination.

k d p

1 0 0

1 2 4

1 3 2

1 4 1

```
    Prim prim = new Prim(7);
    prim.addNode(1, 2, 2);
    prim.addNode(1, 1, 4);
    prim.addNode(1, 4, 3);

    prim.addNode(2, 2, 1);
    prim.addNode(2, 3, 4);
    prim.addNode(2, 10, 6);

    prim.addNode(3, 4, 1);
    prim.addNode(3, 2, 4);
    prim.addNode(3, 5, 6);

    prim.addNode(4, 1, 1);
    prim.addNode(4, 3, 2);
    prim.addNode(4, 2 ,3);
    prim.addNode(4, 7, 5);
    prim.addNode(4, 8, 6);
    prim.addNode(4, 4, 7);

    prim.addNode(5, 10, 2);
    prim.addNode(5, 7, 4);
    prim.addNode(5, 6, 7);

    prim.addNode(6, 5, 3);
    prim.addNode(6, 8, 4);
    prim.addNode(6, 1, 7);

    prim.addNode(7, 4, 4);
    prim.addNode(7, 6, 5);
    prim.addNode(7, 1, 6);

    prim.MST(4);
```

Also generates proper results when printing table:

1 1 4

1 2 1

1 2 4

1 0 0

1 6 7

1 1 7

1 4 4

However if I create the following graph:

```
 Prim prim = new Prim(6);
    prim.addNode(1, 4, 2);
    prim.addNode(1, 5, 6);
    prim.addNode(1, 3, 4);

    prim.addNode(2, 4, 1);
    prim.addNode(2, 3, 3);
    prim.addNode(2, 4, 4);
    prim.addNode(2, 4, 5);

    prim.addNode(3, 3, 2);
    prim.addNode(3, 2, 4);


    prim.addNode(4, 2, 3);
    prim.addNode(4, 4, 2);
    prim.addNode(4, 3 ,1);
    prim.addNode(4, 3, 5);


    prim.addNode(5, 3, 4);
    prim.addNode(5, 4, 2);
    prim.addNode(5, 1, 6);

    prim.addNode(6, 5, 1);
    prim.addNode(6, 1, 5);

     prim.MST(4);
```

I get the following results:

1 3 4

1 3 3

1 2 4

1 0 0

1 1 6

1 2147483647 0

In other words the last two rows are incorrect, if it helps this is the link to the last graphs picture on the internet: http://users.monash.edu/~lloyd/tilde/CSC2/CSE2304/Notes/17MST2.shtml

Basically, I'm storing my vertices in an array of linked lists. The first index in the array contains a linked list of all nodes adjacent to first vertex and so on. Each node has the following data members:

1 - cost, distance between source and destination;

2 - Source, the vertex;

3 - *Dest* or the destination node.

The table `t` has 3 columns, first is whether the node is known or not, the second is the cost and the third is the path, or number of source node.
The start is basically which node I wanna start from in this undirected graph.
Finally,I would like to add that I am actually using this algorithm in a google map to find shortest straight path between two points. When I tried first two examples, I thought my algorithm was correct so I applied it to my real problem, however had incorrect results, so I picked a random graph from the internet and passed it through my algorithm to see if it really worked, turns out it didn't.
Thanks you in advance,  please help.

Comment: *"correct results in some cases, yet incorrect, or partially correct results in other cases"*, what are those cases?

Comment: Don't mix Arrays with Collections that's a bad ideia.

Comment: This code should not compile.   So your statement about "producing correct results" is misleading.  If you want help debugging your code, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Either give concrete examples of what isn't working and when, or just use google to find a working implementation...

Comment: There you go, I wrote the complete code with examples, hope it helps.